# Regex for matching URL with 6 digit prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a randomly generated instance URL, which contains varying 6 digit codes depending on the environment it's rendered in. I have been trying to implement a version of [this guide.](https://laura.mosher.tech/2020/10/19/rack-cors-origins-via-env-var-and-regex/) . However, having not used a regexp before I'm finding this more confusing to implement, what is the best and safest way to capture such a URL?

example:

```
123675.apps.testwebsite.com
```

What I have tried:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}\.--apps.testwebsite.com \z
```

How it will be used:

```
 allow do
  origins "localhost:3000", "127.0.0.1:3000",
          /\Ahttp:\/\/192\.168\.0\.\d{1,3}(:\d+)?\z/ 
          # Here needs to be a Regexp that validates the entire URL.
end
```

Comment: `"123675.apps.testwebsite.com".match?(/\A[0-9]{1,6}\.apps\.testwebsite\.com\z/)` => `true`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, but he needs to validate all 6 digit, so it should be only {6}, right?

Comment: If there must be exactly 6, `/\A[0-9]{6}\.apps\.testwebsite\.com\z/`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
my_string = '123679.apps.testwebsite.com'
string_check = my_string.match(/^[0-9]{6}.apps.testwebsite.com/)
=> #<MatchData "123679.apps.testwebsite.com">

"123675.apps.testwebsite.com".match?(/^[0-9]{6}.apps.testwebsite.com/)
=> true
```

This will match only if there are 6 digits followed by `.apps.testwebsite.com`

Comment: I should have written my question better, the regex needs to validate that the whole URL is there, so match that it's a 6 digit pin, followed by the above URL ".apps.testwebsite.com"

Comment: Ok, check my edit